# Linear models: can we trust estimated coefficients when some are not estimatable?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a dataset where `treatment` and `subject` play a role in how the data is behaving. I am fitting a linear model where I am modeling feature abundance as function of both covariates. My aim is to perform comparisons at `treatment` level while removing the effect of `subject` on the data. However, in some cases I have some `subjects` that are only present in some of the treatments, i.e. their coefficients are not estimatable since they are correlated with treatment, and thus for one treatment group it is confounded by `subject`.

My question is thus if I can still trust the estimates of the remaining coefficients for `treatment`? I do not get any warnings but conceptually I'm not sure if it is plausible to trust the `treatment` coefficients, even bearing in mind that for some they may not have been able to decouple `subject` effect?